# pnpm 'No authorization header was set for the request', private packages in Dockerfile

Tags: npm, dockerfile, pnpm

I'm trying to install packages that I know are in our private npm registry, I have tested the package URL exists with Postman and cURL, using the auth header containing the `NPM_TOKEN` that I'm passing in to build the Docker image, but when I'm running `docker build` locally it's not working.

Command I'm running:
`docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN="**REDACTED**" -t docker-image-test . --no-cache`

Here's a shortened version of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20-bookworm

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ARG NPM_TOKEN

....

RUN apt update

RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN npm config set '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken' "${NPM_TOKEN}"

# Check token with cURL command
RUN curl  https://registry.npmjs.org/@**REDACTED**/test-client -H "Authorization: Bearer ${NPM_TOKEN}" && echo "got package"

USER node

COPY --chown=node:node package.json package.json
COPY --chown=node:node tsconfig.json tsconfig.json
COPY --chown=node:node pnpm-lock.yaml pnpm-lock.yaml

RUN pnpm install

COPY --chown=node:node src src
```

and the error:

> => ERROR [14/15] RUN pnpm install
> [14/15] RUN pnpm install:
> 1.412 Progress: resolved 0, reused 0, downloaded 1, added 0
> 1.997  ERR_PNPM_FETCH_404  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@**REDACTED**%2Ftest-client: Not Found - 404
> 1.997
> 1.997 This error happened while installing a direct dependency of /**REDACTED**
> 1.997
> 1.997 @**REDACTED**/test-client is not in the npm registry, or you have no permission to fetch it.
> 1.997
> 1.997 No authorization header was set for the request.

I have removed the private package @account name for security reasons and changed the package name but have not otherwise edited the error above.

I have also tried running `echo //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN} > .npmrc` instead of the `npm config set` but they look to do the same thing anyway.

Is there a debug command I can run to display the headers that are being sent in the pnpm install command? Or any ideas what I could be missing?